# Populate inputs on selects JQUERY

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i have a dropdown menu generated by my php when the page loads filling with my rows in the sql table, being the table ID(Value) and they NAME.

```
<select>
<option value="0"></option>
<option value=6>Alientech</option>
<option value=2>FNAC</option>
<option value=5>Logitech</option>
<option value=1>MHR</option>
</select>
```

Then i have:

```
<input type="text" name="editname">
<input type="text" name="editmail">
<input type="text" name="editwebsite">
<input type="text" name="editphone">
<input type="text" name="editfax">
<input type="text" name="editadress">
<input type="text" name="editincharge">
```

What i want to do is on selecting the option above he gets the id of the row in mysql and fills the inputs accordingly to the values in the SQL table so a person can edit the values on submitting the form.

How can i with jQuery do this?

Comment: havent tryed nothing been searching in google for some kind of tuturial so i can do this... because i dont want to reload all the page to do this using only php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could reload the page :

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
    <select name="myselect">
        <option value="0" disabled="disabled"></option>
        <option value=6>Alientech</option>
        <option value=2>FNAC</option>
        <option value=5>Logitech</option>
        <option value=1>MHR</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

With a little bit of jQuery...

```
$("form#myform select").change(function(){
    $("form#myform").submit(); // Submit the form if the value is changed.
});
```

And when you load your page, if you find a value for `$_POST["myselect"]` then you have to load something in the fields (except if it's 0).

You could also do things asynchronously with Ajax (instead of submitting the form, send a HTTP request and parses the result to fill the form). However, if the purpose of your page is *only* to edit an entry, the you should use the above method.

Ajax reference : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Then use Ajax, see the end of my answer, and azngunit81's one :)

Answer (score 1):

Where is your code attempt?

The way to do this is on select of the jquery
you would take the value of the select where 
`<select id="some_id">`
also you will need to ID all your fields of input.
Your PHP script should return a JSON where your on success you parse the JSON and set it to the value of your INPUT field via ID.

```
$.ajax({
url: some_php_mysql.php
 type:post,
 data: {some_id:$('#some_id').val()},
success:function(data){
//json object returned - parse and then ID each value
});
```